# Calculate mean of certain part of numpy array (image)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to calculate the mean of a certain part of an image (a numpy array).
The image contains a dog, and I have a mask that can black out all pixels except for the dog using bitwise_and.
I can then calculate the mean intensity of the dog without the surrounding as

```
masked_dog_image = cv2.bitwise_and(dog_image,dog_mask)
dog_image_no_zeros = masked_dog_image[masked_dog_image > 0].
np.mean(dog_images_no_zeros)
```

HOWEVER, in think it is unnecessary to create masked_dog_image and then dog_image_no_zeros just to find this mean value.
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean `np.mean(masked_dog_image[masked_dog_image > 0])`?  I have a feeling I’ve missed a detail. If so, please update the question to clarify the requirement(s).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I fixed the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `dog_mask` to index into the image and calculate the mean of the resulting pixels:

```
np.mean(dog_image[dog_mask > 0])
```

I've made the `dog_mask` of type `bool` on purpose to ensure that we are properly indexing with a Boolean mask.  I am making no assumptions as to the data type of your mask.